# Single model using many-to-many relationship with several other models

Tags: eloquent, eloquent-relationship, laravel-7

I want to have a single table containing information about people (name, phone, email) called `contacts` that can then be associated with several other tables (`clients`, `properties`, `jobs`). However, I have no clue how to approach this through Eloquent. I considered having 2 additional fields in the `contacts` table, an `entity_id` and an `entity_type` to identify the associated records in the other tables, but I am hoping there is a cleaner, more Laravel way to accomplish this.

*create_contacts_table.php*

`Schema::create('contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->id();
  $table->string('first_name')->nullable();
  $table->string('last_name')->nullable();
  $table->string('phone')->nullable();
  $table->string('email')->nullable();
  $table->timestamps();
});`

*create_clients_table.php*

`Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('address_1');
    $table->string('address_2')->nullable();
    $table->string('city')->nullable();
    $table->string('state')->nullable();
    $table->integer('zip_code')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});`

*create_properties_table.php*

`Schema::create('properties', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('address_1');
    $table->string('address_2')->nullable();
    $table->string('city');
    $table->string('state');
    $table->integer('zip_code');
    $table->timestamps();
});`

Comment: this is literally the way Laravel wants it, check this out https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations ... otherwise you have to specify a pivot table for each relation, but in my opinion the solution that laravel use to solve this problem is more clear, and more easy to use... obviously you have to choose the one that is the type of the relation between contacts and jobs, and apply to that the polymorphic code Laravel wants

Comment: Thank you! I was missing the polymorphic term in my searches so this never came up. +1